# Is there any way to reopen a question that I believe was incorrectly closed?

Tags: discussion, reopen-closed

I was looking for the most efficient way to solve the problem in code within a reasonable range of accuracy. I was not looking for a way to calculate it by hand or even for an answer to the problem (which I already had) but for the best/most efficient methods to approach this programmatically. It seems people perhaps saw a diagram and marked it as off-topic automatically?

[Best way to find the Coordinates of a Point on a Line-Segment a specified Distance Away from another Point](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7280049/best-way-to-find-the-coordinates-of-a-point-on-a-line-segment-a-specified-distanc)

Answer (score 9):

The fact that you're looking for code doesn't come across at all in your question. You don't mention a programming language and the post is tagged [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic).

If you're looking for solutions in multiple languages, you're probably better off posting on [Code Golf and Programming Puzzles](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com) rather than Stack Overflow. And if you're looking for optimized solutions in a particular language, you should edit your question to make that clear.

If you have an existing solution that you want to improve, consider posting on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

With all that said, questions can be reopened by a moderator or via 5 reopen votes from community members. To draw attention to a closed question, you can flag it for moderator review or you can post here on meta, which you already did.

Comment: chat rooms are also a reasonable way of discussing reopening after edits if there's an appropriately topical room.